# How to calculate number combinations of formulas for a number of propositions

Tags: combinatorics

I can see, using a paper, that the number of different combinations of forumals (in the sense extensively discussed in the comments) that one proposition can have is $4$, and even that the number for two propositions is $16$.

EDIT: These are the ones for one proposition:

p

0 0 0  1 1

1 0 1  0 1

We could basically see the second colum (first of combinations) as the function 0, the third as p, the fourth as -p and the fifth as 1

And I can understand that for $4$ would be $256$ and for $4$ $65536$. Because basically it's squaring the previous.

But not sure how does that fit into combinations, variations, etc... I mean, I kind of guess, by observations but wouldn't be able to phrase that in a way of saying "the number of truth tables for a given number of propositions is the equal to the combination (or whatever is applicable) of those numbers..."

Is there an easy way to state that.

Thanks

Comment: **Hint.** In a truth table format with $k$ cells, the number of truth tables is $2^k$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: I obviously missing something.  What do you mean be number of different truth tables? It seems to me there is always 1 truth table.  And for n propositions the one truth table with have $2^n$ entries.  So I don't unstand why 2 propositions will have 16 tables.  I imagine it has one table wth the 4 lines: Ptrue,Qtrue: Pfalse,Qtrue; Ptrue, Qfalse; Pfalse, Qfalse.  So obviously I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Thanks @brianTung for your insightful comment

Comment: @fleablood, by different truth tables I mean the different results you can assign to those 4 lines that you mention (i.e. one will be all 0's, other all 1's, other would be the AND operator, other the OR etc..)

Comment: I'm still confused.  The four lines have all the results already..  AND, OR etc will all have only one option.  You can't have P false Q false and P AND Q true after all.  Can you tell me what the 4 tables of a single proposition are?  Say you have P.  What are the 4 tables?

Comment: @fleablood, I put them in the edit, although I will try to format them properly when I can take a look on how to do it (have to "wake up" in a bit). The upper row is just how we could name that partifular column (i.e. truth table)

Comment: It seems to me that you are not looking for the number of truth tables, but the number of logically distinct formulas with however many propositions. If I am correct about that, you should edit the question, as the terminology you use is highly nonstandard.

Comment: Okay... now that you've posted the tables, can you explain what they mean? Why do you need a column for False, for True and of -p and why do you have two columns for p?  I'm still utterly confused and perplexed and don't know what you are asking.

Comment: @SeanEnglish, guess the correct name is truth value as I edited

Comment: @fleablood, my intention was not to create a column for false, true.. but to name the functions that have that truth value for one proposition (hope get the terminology right). Understand that it was even more confusing, my bad

Comment: Well, everyone else seemed to have understood it...

Comment: @mitomed Truth value is still not the correct word. The truth value of a statement is either "true" or "false" so for any number of propositions, there are always exactly two truth values. That is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @SeanEnglish, now?

Comment: @mitomed no, it is nor a combination of truth values. Like I said, you are looking dor the number of "logically distinct formulas on $n$ propositions"

Comment: @SeanEnglish, would you call each of the columns of a truth table "formulas"?

Comment: in a strict sense, no, they are different objects, but there is a natural bijection between them. Each column represents a formula and gives the truth value of that formula given the truth values of the atomic constituents. We get distinct columns iff they represent distinct formulas. This bijection shows that what you are looking for is the number of distinct formulas on $n$ atomic propositions. E.g., in the case of $n=1$, you have four distinct formulas, $P$, $\lnot P$, $P\land\lnot P$ and $P\lor\lnot P$. Any other formula using only one proposition will be equivalent to one of these four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write down a truth table for $n$ propositions, you have to assign True or False to each of the $2^n$ possible combinations of truth values that those propositions can take.

Thus you have to choose True or False $2^n$ times; the number of ways to do this is $2 \times 2 \times \cdots \times 2$, where there are $2^n$ factors, or $2^{2^n}$.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  What do you mean by possible combinations of truth values the proposition can take.  If you have to propositions P,Q, you have for possible combinations of assigned truth values. (P and Q both true, both false, P true Q false, P false Q true).  What more does a truth table need?  What purpose does assigning Ptrue; Qfalse to FALSE do and what does it mean?